# var_dump showing me unexpected results

Tags: php, windows

am tying to create a simple application to test logging in and out using a file based authentication but i have run into a bit of a snug i can't wrap my head around.

Here are the contents of the text file that am using to test my application which is named **filetest_02.txt**

```
david, codeslave
chris, bigboss
```

Am also using to PHP scripts to do the testing
Here are the contents for **login.php**

```
    <?php

     $error = '';

    if ( isset($_POST['login']) ) {
    session_start();
    $username = trim( $_POST['username'] );
    $password = trim( $_POST['pwd']  );
    // location of usernames and passwords
    $userlist = 'C:/private/filetest_02.txt';
    // location to redirect on success
    $redirect = 'http://localhost/php/powers/solutions/ch09/menu.php';
    require_once './includes/authenticate.inc.php';
    }

   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if ( $error ) : ?>
        <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
            <p>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input name="login" type="submit" id="login" value="Log in">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here are the contents for **authenticate.inc.php**

```
<?php

if ( !file_exists($userlist) || !is_readable($userlist) ) {
    $error = 'Login facility unavailable. Please try later.';
} else {
    // read the file into an array called $users
    $users = file( $userlist );
    // loop through the array to process each line
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++ ) {
        // separate each element and store in a temporary array
        $tmp = explode( ', ', $users[$i] );
        var_dump($tmp);
        $name = trim($tmp[0]);
        $pwd = trim($tmp[1]);
        var_dump( $name, $pwd );
        var_dump( $_POST );
        // check for a matching record
        if ( $name == $username && $pwd == $password ) {
            $_SESSION['authenticated'] = 'Jethro Tull';
            session_regenerate_id();
            break;
        }
    }
    // if the session variable has been set, redirect
    if ( isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) ) {
        /* header( "Location: $redirect" );
        exit; */
    } else {
        $error = 'Invalid username or password.';
    }
}
```

The trouble is when i click the login button on **login.php**, i get the following output
[image]

Why is the var_dump output showing the length of string 'david' to be equal to 8 even to 8 even after trimming it? What could be causing all this?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

var_dump probably showed you the initialization of david with spaces, but you can see it recognized its cut afterwards. Is this doing anything unwanted in your code?

Also if this is for an actual website and you are just not playing around, I would not store passwords in your files without them being salted and hashed.

Also, taking from the PHP manual:

> string(32) "        These are a few words :) ...  "
>   string(16) "    Example string
>   "
>   string(11) "Hello World"
>
> string(28) "These are a few words :) ..."
>   string(24) "These are a few words :)"
>   string(5) "o Wor"
>   string(9) "ello Worl"
>   string(14) "Example string"

var_dump showed the initialization and the trims afterwards.

Comment: Yes am playing around but as you can see from the code that i have written, i am supposed to test for equality on the username and password from the file with the username and password from my form and i think the reason the session is not being set is because the username from the file and from the form are obviously not equal because of there lengths

Comment: nevermind, just debug and trace your code. I have a log in system but it looks too different from yours to share. I'd debug it but I don't have the files.